# Synthetic Control Asymptotics

Tags: econometrics, synthetic-control

I'm aware of the basics of the synthetic control method, and that permutation tests are commonly used for inference.

Are there papers that develop asymptotic theory? i.e. if the regression approach to create weights is used (as in the *synth* command), and the number of control groups and pre-treatment time periods goes to infinity, are there papers proving consistency or asymptotic normality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some work on the asymptotic consistency like the [Robust Synthetic Control by Amjad et al (2018)](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume19/17-777.pdf), also the study of [Firpo and Possebom 2016](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/jci-2016-0026/html) discusses asymptotic inference.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for this. It looks like there isn't anything of the "Consistent and Asymptotically Normal" result as GMM or MLE do. I guess also asymptotics aren't really relevant because there are often few controls and time periods.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MichaelGmeiner oh I thought you will be happy with just some asymptotic inference, as you say it is very unlikely it would be possible to have  asymptotic normality with this sort of model

Comment: Oh, I'm happy you sent these! It's good to be aware that there is some work on the subject.

Comment: Also @1muflon1 I don't know if you care, but I found another. https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/01621459.2021.1965613?casa_token=clj1BGUMYb0AAAAA%3AjOHH1q3RRe8VF7HT0uiDYc7Z3XvIlXlW9REFFdNiw7yqW_GGpeZTSNa8hLjIA6Qxojk1P-R9Dz4